# Interpret this SQL in to English

Tags: sql, postgresql

I've been given the task of rewriting certain sections of this SQL but am having trouble interpreting it completely. In plain English could an SQL master explain what is happening from "appointments_2015 AS" to the end.

```
CREATE TABLE appointment (
emp_id integer NOT NULL,
jobtitle varchar(128) NOT NULL,
salary decimal(10,2) NOT NULL,
start_date date NOT NULL,
end_date date NULL
);

ALTER TABLE appointment ADD CONSTRAINT pkey_appointment PRIMARY KEY 
(emp_id, jobtitle, start_date);
ALTER TABLE appointment ADD CONSTRAINT chk_appointment_period CHECK 
(start_date <= end_date);


WITH current_employees AS (
SELECT DISTINCT emp_id
FROM appointment
WHERE end_date IS NULL
),
appointments_2015 AS (
SELECT a.emp_id, salary,
CASE WHEN start_date < ’2015-01-01’ THEN ’2015-01-01’ ELSE start_date END 
AS start_date,
CASE WHEN end_date < ’2016-01-01’ THEN end_date ELSE ’2015-12-31’ END AS 
end_date
FROM appointment a
JOIN current_employees ce ON a.emp_id = ce.emp_id
WHERE start_date < ’2016-01-01’ AND (end_date >= ’2015-01-01’ OR end_date 
IS NULL)
)
SELECT 
  emp_id,
  SUM( salary * (end_date - start_date + 1) / 365 ) AS total
FROM appointments_2015
GROUP BY emp_id
```

Comment: t.harris:  Do a search for common table expressions.  They are like embedded temp tables each separated by a comma and then applied to the last statement.   This does sounds like homework...;)

Comment: It's creating a table without inserting rows then querying it...so 'returning zero rows' is the simple answer as to what this is doing.  Less tongue in cheek, the query is nesting temp tables (nested views pretty much) to get the salary expended in each appointment.  This can be written as one statement without the nesting.

Comment: In in plain english, "list income for now-current employees for the year 2015"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What that code is doing is essentially creating a temporary table with the alias appointments_2015.  That temp table will have the results from the query inside the AS () section.

The SELECT statement that follows is pulling from that appointments_2015 temp table.

Docs can be found here: [WITH queries Docs](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/queries-with.html)

The CASE WHEN is like an IF statement.  CASE WHEN x THEN y ELSE z END is equivalent to IF x THEN y ELSE z

Answer (score 0):

`appointments_2015 AS ( more sql )` You're creating a "virtual table" from the queries inside of the parenthesis.

Inside that your selecting `start_date` and `end_date` with a condition: "if it's older than `2015-01-01` set it to `2015-01-01` else use the original value. Then your joining in another table called `"current_employees"` where `start_date` is before `2016-01-01` and `end_date` is greater than or equal to `2015-01-01`, or doesn't have a value.

When the "virtual table" has been created you query it and select `emp_id` and a SUM of a salary

Answer (score 0):

Two temporary tables are created: `current_employees` and `appointments_2015`. Syntax:

```
WITH current_employees AS ( .... ),
     appointments_2015 AS ( .... )
```

The last `SELECT` statement generates the result dataset: the total amount of salary in year 2015 per employee who started on or prior to Dec 31, 2015 and is still working (current employee).